# nginx controller with sigle signon integration, page redirection doesnt work

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have an requirement to setup nginx ingres controller on AKS and make it act as LB for externally deployed service on Virtual Machine. Then enable SSO login with our internal SSO server.

I  have been able to setup the ingress controller and service access, however when I enable sso redirection, URL doesnt show the applciation page.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: test
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.0.0.10
    ports:
      - port: 8080 

---  
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sso-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "https://ssotest.example.com/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=XYZ&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://home.example.com/test"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: >
      proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic
      lajdlajflajfldjadlfdjadlkfjlakdfjlkadfjalklkajsdlljl";
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "nginx-aks.example.com"
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:   
              number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - nginx-aks.example.com
      secretName: secret-6
    - hosts:
        - nginx-aks.example.com
      secretName: secret-4
```

When i comment out annotion, URL `nginx-aks.example.com/test` works and take me to application. But when SSO is enabled and try the URL which is configured on Azure Application Gateway, it goes to not found page

https://home.example.com/test

Our requirement should
ttps://home.example.com/test hit goes to SSO login, once login successful it should show the backend application page.

Happy to share more info if anyone looking for.

Everything possibble